# How do I get the text from a .txt file and write it in a new sheet in the same excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I want a whole text file to enter into a new sheet in excel. Right now I am only getting all values in to one cell, I want it to look like in the text file. Like every row get one row in excel.

I have tried this tutorial but this doesn't get it.

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html

Comment: The simplest way is to use `Workbooks.Open(yourTextFilePathHere)`

Comment: Record a macro, then import your text file and follow the wizard. When you are done, stop recording and look at the generated code.

Comment: You can use Power Query for this.  Import the text file; process it so it displays properly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for you who wants to know how check below

```
Sub GetText()
Dim SheetName As String
Dim TMPWorkBook As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
Dim TxtFilePath As String
Dim TxtFileName As String

Set WB = ThisWorkbook

SheetName = "Test_Result"
TxtFileName = "C:\getitdone.txt"

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    TxtFileName _
    , Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
    Array(2, 1)), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set TMPWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Getitdone.xlsm").Activate
Sheets.Add.Name = "Data"
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```